# PHP: Can't output the number 0

Tags: php, wordpress

I have an input box where a user can input a number and then that number will be outputted into an html page. It all works fine except when you enter in the number 0 it doesn't output anything but it needs to say 0. This is a live baseball game scoring plugin I wrote for WordPress so I need "Inning 1" to read "0" if no runs were scored. Here is the gist of my code:

```
$t1Inning1 = ( $instance['t1Inning1'] ) ? $instance['t1Inning1'] : '-';

<div><?php echo $t1Inning1 ?></div>

<label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('t1Inning1'); ?>">
  <input id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('t1Inning1'); ?>" 
  name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('t1Inning1'); ?>"
  value="<?php echo esc_attr( $instance['t1Inning1'] ); ?>"
  maxlength="2" size="3" />
</label>
```

You can see the output at http://juniorregionals.com/ in the middle left. The '-' is just the default value which doesn't change when you input 0 in the plugin and save it but again I need it to read 0 if you input 0.

Let me know if I need to be more specific

Comment: Try ending your <div><?php echo $t1Inning1 **;** ?></div>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Someone from the WordpressStackexchange site had me add an exact comparison:

```
$t1Inning1 = isset( $instance['t1Inning1'] ) && $instance['t1Inning1'] !== '' ? $instance['t1Inning1'] : '-';
```

and that works flawlessly. Thanks for all your help @Marty. You actually got the ball rolling fast.

Answer (score 3):

You're using the ternary operator on `0` which is a falsy value, e.g.

```
echo 0 ? 1 : 2; // 2
```

Perhaps you meant to check if `$instance["t1Inning1"]` is *set* rather than falsy?

```
$t1Inning1 = isset($instance['t1Inning1']) ? $instance['t1Inning1'] : '-';
```

Comment: That worked. It lets me put in the 0 and it displays the 0. Awesome! I still need the output to have a dash (-) as the value by default. that way the innings that have yet to be played  will show a dash (-) as the score. Which is how it looks if I take out the "isset".

Comment: @agon024 I assume the value is always supplied then, just with some alternate value? Otherwise you would indeed see a dash.

Comment: In the original code: ||  $t1Inning1 = ( $instance['t1Inning1'] ) ? $instance['t1Inning1'] : '-';  || this '-' gave it a default value of a dash. with the isset in there it is just blank.

Comment: isnt this my correct format: $items = isset(condition) ? value_if_condition_true : value_if_condition_false;

Comment: Someone has the know the answer. I am running out of time to get this working. Plzzzzz help :)

Comment: @agon024 What problem are you facing exactly? You've implemented my code and are seeing zeros instead of `-`?

Comment: ya, after adding the isset, when an input field is empty it doesn't display anything. I need it to display a dash by default if no number is put in. see it at juniorregionals.com on the left side. It has the dashes now but that is because I visically put them in all the input boxes and saved it in the widget. So to be clear with "isset" the number 0 shows in the output(on the home page of juniorregionals.com) but any input field that is empty needs to output a dash (-) as the default value which it is not doing now.